# Memory semantics of initialization in multithread environment (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, memory-fences

I am not certain of the memory semantics of C++ initialization process. 
Let's say we have the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void func(int* arr, int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *a = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    // Do I need some sort of memory barrier here?
    std::thread t(func, a, 10);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Will the new thread see an array initialized properly? Or do I need the insert some sort of memory barrier in between. How does C++ language define the memory semantics for the initialization?

My concern is that all the writes to array **a[10]** may sit in one cpu's write buffer, and we start a new thread on a different cpu, which may not observe the initialization writes.

Do we need memory fence for initialization to be able to be observed by later issued thread running on a different cpus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "happens-before" relationship between operations in the parent prior to executing the thread constructor, and the thread procedure running in the child.  In particular the Standard says (`f` being the thread procedure):

> *Synchronization*: The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

This is found in section `[thread.thread.constr]`

Comment: Thanks for the citing. I had a hard time reading the standard. I found your quotes. By "synchronizes with", I suppose it means the compiler might insert fence right before the invocation of the copy of f to make sure all the stores before the invocation of f will be observed?

Comment: @OliverYoung: The standard doesn't say anything about memory fences, because not all CPU architectures need them.  The standard says where the compiler needs to ensure that side effects are visible, and where operations overlap (creating a race condition), and the compiler is responsible for using whatever CPU feature gives the specified behavior.

Comment: I see. Just to be very clear, the initialization part synchronizes / "happens-before" invocations of the copy of f. This means there's no race condition and need no synchronization operations, right?

Comment: @OliverYoung: Correct.  Although it would be more correct to say "need no additional synchronization operations", because starting the thread already is a synchronization operation, as documented by this standard quote.